# Setting up basic pararrayfun in GNU Octave

Tags: multithreading, octave

I have a file `testPowr.m`

```
function testPowr(x)
   printf(x^2)
   end
```

I am trying the following in another file `main.m` in the same folder as `testPowr.m`:

```
clear; clc;
pkg load parallel;
vector = 1:10;
fun = @(x) x^2;
pararrayfun(nproc, @(n) testPowr(n), vector)
%a2 = pararrayfun(nproc, fun, vector)
```

But `testPowr` seems not visible to `pararrayfun` as the commented line above works. I have tried multiple different syntax but I am unable to get it right.

I am getting the following error in one of the syntax:

```
execution error
error: __parcellfun_get_next_result__: could not receive result
error: called from
    parcellfun at line 201 column 16
    pararrayfun at line 85 column 28
    main at line 5 column 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `testPowr` does not return a value.

`pararrayfun` collects the return value of each function call but all your function does is print the result to stdout. You can fix this by returning something, like so:

```
function xp = testPowr (x)
  xp = x^2;
endfunction
```

Your script will then work fine:

```
octave> pkg load parallel;
octave> rv = pararrayfun (nproc, @(n) testPowr(n), 1:10)
parcellfun: 10/10 jobs done
rv =

     1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100
```

Comment: Why does the print statement not work however? In Python you don't need to return a value for the multiprocessing to work.

Comment: There's two issues: 1) your call to `printf` was just wrong (see the documentation for `printf`) maybe you meant to use disp?, 2) there's nothing wrong with printing stuff from the other processes (but beware of garbling output when multiple processes print at the same time) but the way `pararrayfun` works is that the function being parallelized must return something (even if only a status code). If you don't want it, wrap the function to something that does return something.