# pararrayfun 'could not receive result' error although FUN returns a value

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, functional-programming, octave

I have just installed [`parallel`](https://wiki.octave.org/Parallel_package) on my machine (Linux Mint 20, Octave version: 5.2.0).

I am trying to run an example code taken from [here](https://wiki.octave.org/wiki/images/e/e9/Examples_of_how_to_use_parrarrayfun.pdf) but I get this error with `pararrayfun`:

```
error: 'myfun' undefined near line 1 column 6
execution error
error: __parcellfun_get_next_result__: could not receive result
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70595650/1979665) that `pararrayfun` requires a return value to work, which is the case in the example (see code below).

```
# In this script 4 ways of calculating the values of a one-dimensional function
# are compared, the time taken by each way is measured and it is verified that
# there are no discrepancies in the results.
pkg load parallel

nmax = 10000; # Number of points where the function is calculated

function [a,b] = myfun(n); # Function used in this test
  a = pi*(n-2)/n;
  f = @(x) (cos(x).^n + sin(x).^(n-1));
  b = quadgk(f,0,a);
endfunction

# Fist method, using a for loop, defining the function to calculate
# within the loop.
tic
for n = 1:nmax;
  a1(n) = pi*(n-2)/n;
  b1(n) = quadgk(@(x) (cos(x).^n + sin(x).^(n-1)),0,a1(n));
endfor
t1 = toc

# Second method, using a for loop and calling "myfun"
tic
for n = 1:nmax;
  [a2(n),b2(n)] = myfun(n);
endfor
t2= toc

# Third method, using arrayfun to call "myfun"
tic
ni = 1:nmax;
[a3,b3] = arrayfun("myfun",ni);
t3 = toc

# Forth method, using parrayfun to call "myfun"
tic
ni = 1:nmax;
[a4,b4] = pararrayfun(4,@(n) myfun(n),ni);
t4 = toc

# Are discrepancies in the results?
discrepancies_1 = max(a2-a1) + max(b2-b1) + max(a3-a1)
discrepancies_2 = max(b3-b1) + max(a4-a1) + max(b4-b1)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I have no experience at all with this package, but assuming it starts new processes like MATLAB’s Parallel Processing Toolbox, I would guess that `myfun` is defined in the main process, but not in the worker ones. Because you define it inline. If you make it its own M-file, it should work.

Comment: Or, given the example in the package docs, do `@myfun` instead of `@(n) myfun(n)`. Or maybe you need to define `fun=@myfun` first, on a separate line, so that it’s a variable that can be copied over instead of a function name?

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo and thanks for your feedback! I just tried adding `fun = @myfun` after `myfun` definition and do `[a4,b4] = pararrayfun(4,@(n) fun(n),ni);` instead, but I get a `function handle points to non-existent function` error now. Maybe it's not what you meant?

Comment: I even tried to move the function definition in a separate file `myfun.m` and call it like `[a4,b4] = pararrayfun(4,@(n) @myfun(n),ni);`, but still no luck `error: @myfun: no function and no method found`. I tested that calling this function now moved in `myfun.m` works with another call (apparently it fails only with `pararrayfun`) :(

Comment: `@(n) fun(n)` is pointless, `fun` is already a handle, it should be just `pararrayfun(4,fun,ni)`. Maybe combine both solutions? `myfun` being an M-file, then do `fun=@myfun` and pass `fun` into `pararrayfun`? ---- Sorry, just throwing ideas out there, this is what I would try to get it to work. Hopefully someone with experience comes by to help you. :)

Comment: No luck, I tried most possible combinations (I even asked Bard which eventually suggested to ask on SO lol). It's strange though since the example was updated recently... Will try on the Octave mailing list meanwhile, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem thanks to [this post](https://octave.discourse.group/t/can-someone-help-with-implementing-pararrayfun-in-my-program/2031/4?u=umbe1987) in the GNU Octave discourse group.

> The way the “parallel” package works in Octave is that it spawns various “independent” instances of Octave and runs the given code in all of those.
> For this to work correctly, all necessary functions must be accessible in all of those instances. If I understand your code correctly, you define myFun inline. That way it will only be defined in the “main” instance.
> Move that function to a dedicated file and store it in a place that is in the load path of all instances. (Maybe use .octaverc to add it to your default load path.)

So basically I had to move my function definition in a separate file "myfun.m" (as also suggested by user Cris Luengo in the comments to my question), and move this file in a folder which is in Octave load path.

To do this, I have create a new dedicated folder ("~/octave/custom_funcs"), and added this to the load path with `addpath("~/octave/custom_funcs")`.

Hope this will be helpful for anybody.

Comment: So the workers do not have the current directory set to the main instance’s current directory? That seems weird to me, I would not have implemented it that way. :(

Comment: Apparently not. I mean, you can use function m files that are inside the directory of the "main" script, but the workers apparently do not use that. With the Octave GUI you can select the "current directory", which I did not notice before, and that wuold probably work as well. Anyway, I also feel this is not straight forward and should be better documented, especially when you take it for granted that an official sample script would work.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is at least a bug in the documentation. You could submit a bug report.

Comment: Already done https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?64813